# sum, min, max & mean of R-values above a regression line in Python

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression

I have a time-series dataframe which i have plotted as below (2 dataframes are plotted together in the picture below)

the line plot lines are **thin** orange & blue lines. the regression line or the trend line of each dataset would be something like the **thick** orange & blue lines respectively.

How do I calculate the sum, min, max & mean of R-values (the distance from the regression line) above & below a regression line separately? That is sum, min, max & mean of the positive R-values & negative R-values separately in python.
There may be a term for what i am trying to do but i am new to statistics & do not know that. Can any one guide me?

[image]

**Update** The data i have is something like below (actual data is much longer). Overall trend is down but there are small upswings in between.

```html
Time Values
101 20.402
102 20.302
103 20.202
104 20.102
105 20.002
106 19.902
107 19.802
108 19.702
109 19.602
110 19.502
111 19.402
112 19.302
113 19.202
114 20.337
115 20.437
116 20.537
117 18.802
118 18.702
119 18.602
120 18.502
121 18.402
122 18.302
123 18.202
124 18.102
125 18.002
126 17.902
127 17.802
128 17.702
129 17.602
130 17.502
131 18.502
132 18.402
133 18.302
134 17.702
135 17.602
136 17.502
137 17.402
138 17.302
139 17.202
140 17.102
141 17.002
```

Comment: Can you provide any code you've used so far?

Comment: I have not used any code so far to calculate the above points since i am new to statistics & don't know how to do it. I have the code below to slice the data from the below function to just plot the data `sns.lineplot(x="Time", y="Values", data=grouped_bel1800, ax=ba)
    sns.lineplot(x="Time", y="Values", data=grouped_bel1800_2, ax=ba)`

Comment: the code below seems to kind work, it calculates the regression line for the wole dataframe & gives the distance. However, since i want the regression line & distance for each group, this is not working for me. Can anyone know how to tweak this? may be a function & apply would work but i am not able to make that work either. Code in below comment

Comment: `model = LinearRegression()
x = data_train_bel1800.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Time'].head(2000)[:,np.newaxis]
y = data_train_bel1800.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Values'].head(2000)
model.fit(x, y)
data_train_bel1800["Distance"] = (data_train_bel1800.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Values'].head(2000)
                                  - model.predict(data_train_bel1800.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Time'].head(2000)[:,np.newaxis]))
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example uses your posted data and calculates positive and negative errors separately, excluding errors of exactly zero.

```
import numpy


xData = numpy.array([101.0, 102.0, 103.0, 104.0, 105.0, 106.0, 107.0, 108.0, 109.0, 110.0, 111.0, 112.0, 113.0, 114.0, 115.0, 116.0, 117.0, 118.0, 119.0, 120.0, 121.0, 122.0, 123.0, 124.0, 125.0, 126.0, 127.0, 128.0, 129.0, 130.0, 131.0, 132.0, 133.0, 134.0, 135.0, 136.0, 137.0, 138.0, 139.0, 140.0, 141.0])
yData = numpy.array([20.402, 20.302, 20.202, 20.102, 20.002, 19.902, 19.802, 19.702, 19.602, 19.502, 19.402, 19.302, 19.202, 20.337, 20.437, 20.537, 18.802, 18.702, 18.602, 18.502, 18.402, 18.302, 18.202, 18.102, 18.002, 17.902, 17.802, 17.702, 17.602, 17.502, 18.502, 18.402, 18.302, 17.702, 17.602, 17.502, 17.402, 17.302, 17.202, 17.102, 17.002])


polynomialOrder = 1 # example straight line

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters = numpy.polyfit(xData, yData, polynomialOrder)
print('Fitted Parameters:', fittedParameters)

modelPredictions = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xData)
fitErrors = modelPredictions - yData

positiveErrors = []
negativeErrors = []

# this logic excludes errors of exactly zero
for error in fitErrors:
    if error < 0.0:
       negativeErrors.append(error)
    if error > 0.0:
       positiveErrors.append(error)

print('Positive error statistics:')
print('    sum =',  numpy.sum(positiveErrors))
print('    min =',  numpy.min(positiveErrors))
print('    max =',  numpy.max(positiveErrors))
print('    mean =', numpy.mean(positiveErrors))

print()

print('Negative error statistics:')
print('    sum =',  numpy.sum(negativeErrors))
print('    min =',  numpy.min(negativeErrors))
print('    max =',  numpy.max(negativeErrors))
print('    mean =', numpy.mean(negativeErrors))
```